# Issue with page life cycle (asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I have got this event in my page aspx.cs:

```
   public void deleteBtn_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{

    UsefulStaticMethods.DeleteComment(int.Parse(e.CommandName));        
}
```

I am trying to delete a comment from the page. The deletion is successful. However, the website interface doesnt update itself after that event happens.

My Page Load is responsible to drawing all the comments on the page with a dynamic button (delete comment).

I know when the delete button fires, the page Load fires before.. and thats a bit is a problem..cause the page load recreates the page interface, while the deleteBtn_click deletes the comment, and I want to update the interface straight away... "Refresh" the page without the comment that was deleted..

If i execute a function to draw the whole table again, it will draw another comment list along with the comment list drawn at the page Load event.
I cant not refuse not to draw the comment list at page_load, cause i need everything recreated at postback time (including the dynamically created button).-cant use !Ispostback

The question is how can i achieve this/overcome the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, if your using data-binding then you can just re-bind the control in question. Perhaps, you should modify your function that draws the comment list to clear the existing list (possible by removing rows from table control or clearing control collection from container panel or placeholder (you can introduce a placeholder control just for clearing purpose)).

Yet another hack to refresh the page is to restart the page-life cycle by doing `Server.Transfer` to the same page. Generally, I wouldn't recommend this approach unless page code structure is very complicated and refreshing the data would take many lines of code.

Comment: I thought to resort to Response.Redirect. The problem is that the changes happen at the event time.. So unless the button event fires somehow before the pageload, it can notify the pageload of the changes. But it doesnt, so page load, loads as usual with not up to date data..cause it fires before the button event that has the update.... if i dont generate all the buttons in the pageload and attach them to a placeholder..no event would fire and nothing will be drawing..cause all the page is created dynamically.. you see?

Comment: Rebinding of controls work at pageload.. but it is a datacontrol,,that accepts a data source.. i see what u mean.. still the button event fires after the page load,,so no deletion changes occur before teh comment list is drawn

Comment: @Dmitry, I am not suggesting you to change the page_load. I am simply saying that on button click, just re-bind the data (or recreate control tree for comment list). You shouldn't use `Response.Redirect` as it means unnecessary round-trip to client - `Server.Transfer` is certainly better alternative.

Comment: Thanks..recreate control tree where? at the button event , recreating anything is useless. At the pageload or preInit, that is the only time i can recreate the controls.. How do you mean to rebind them.. I have a table with buttons & labels dynamically recreated on every page load..

Comment: @Dimitry, why can't u re-create your table on button click? Just throw away the earlier table by clearing its parent and run the code the creates the table again. In case, you are creating your table by using controls such as Repeater/ListView then you can re-bind that control again to refresh the control tree.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebind control. Suppose your button is in Grid than you need to Rebind() grid. If not than there is one more way. Put Contents in Update panel and set Update panel Trigger with Delete button. SO when Delete button is clicked that update panel cause Update.

Answer (score -1):

Use data list or repeater server control to display comments and than bind the server control again  after deletion. Use  !Ispostback on Page_Load.

Comment: i told you !isPostback would never work.. my whole page is dynamically created..it has one placeholder on the page only..the data controls sound interesting, but i want to do without them for now